# Show path of folder after following search result

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

Usually I click on `open folder location`. If not - I can't go to the containing folder.

But if I want to view multiple results at the same time - that doesn't work. (`open in new window` doesn't allow going to the containing folder either.)

Comment: how about Shift + `open folder location`?

Comment: @Divin3 Perfect. I didn't know about that. You can convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To open the containing folder of a file listed in the search field in a new window, just press and hold the shift key while selecting `open folder location`.